# How can I target one event element in Fullcalendar of an event with multiple resources in event.resourceIds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to add the following functionality to my Fullcalendar application:

- An event is added to the calendar view that has multiple resources in the resourceIds array
- Out of the events that are rendered in the view only one is editable (the main event) and the rest only adjusts accordingly when this main event is edited

For this to work I need to have some sort of check in the eventRender function of Fullcalendar like the following:

```
if (event.mainResource != craftField.id) {
    event.editable = false;
}
```

I tried to do this by checking event.mainResource (custom property) against event.resourceIds, however, the event rendering of an event with multiple resourceIds is only handled once since there is only one event to be placed in the view. Meaning that when setting the property

```
event.editable = false;
```

for example, all event elements of this event in the view are uneditable instead of just the shadow events.

I expect to have one main event that is editable with multiple shadow events which are uneditable on themselves but do change with the main event accordingly. For now I do have the main event and shadow events, but all of them are editable.

Comment: how about a different approach where any of the events is editable, but you write code to ensure that any change to an individual event is also copied to the other events? If you link them by some common ID (e.g. via a custom property) it will be easy enough to identify the associated events. That way it's arguably a bit more user-friendly since the user doesn't have to know which one is going to be editable.

Comment: My main point not to do this is that Fullcalendar already has the built-in functionality to adjust all events at the same time. Me building the same thing is like reinventing the wheel... The idea also is for me to add a lock-icon of some sort to events that are unchangeable so that the UI does show which events are not editable.

Comment: "My main point not to do this is that Fullcalendar already has the built-in functionality to adjust all events at the same time"...ok so that's even better, you don't need to do any work, and the page is more user-friendly. I'm not really seeing the point of locking it down. What value does that add for the end-user?

Comment: The point of locking shadow events is because this ensures that the event data changes happen on the resource the event is originally from. It needs to be clear for the users for whom the event is originally planned. This is not clear when there is no visual and/or functional difference between these planned events.

Comment: " this ensures that the event data changes happen on the resource the event is originally from"...but if the events are linked, then any changes to one will definitely happen to the others at the same time, so it will always be changed on the original resource as well. And if you only have one entry in the database to cover all these, then it will always update the right record. I take your point about it being clear where the event originated though. If, as you state, eventRender only fires one for a set of linked events like this, then not sure how you would really solve that, sorry

Comment: I get your point, I will look into the possibilities. Thanks for the help!